# Live user not found in stage and dev

Tags: acquia-cloud

I am new to Acquia.

I have got access to the backend of drupal live instance. I cannot login to stage or dev instance.

1. Should a new user be created for every instance separately?
2. What should I do to login to the dev and stage instance?

Currently I am using Acquia Dev Desktop to pull the files locally.

What should I do to get access to the other 2 instances? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acquia works on a three-environment system. When working in such a system, code moves up, from dev -> stage -> prod, while databases move down from prod -> stage -> dev.

You should always consider content on dev and stage, such as nodes, users, taxonomies etc, as temporary. This is because the way to migrate content is by migrating the entire database from prod -> stage/dev, or sometimes from stage -> dev.

In order to get your user on all environments, you would create the user on prod, then migrate that database to stage and dev. You will then be able to log in with your user on those environments.

Comment: So, I will have to Copy the database from live->stage and stage->dev. Right? Then can use the same credentials that i use in live.

What about the database name, username etc? will it be taken care of automatically?

Comment: You can drag and drop the database in the Acquia interface. You don’t have to handle the database credentials